# Why does this Fibonacci evaluate much faster in Python than Haskell

Tags: python, haskell

I have an algorithm for calculating the nth Fibonacci number, in Python it's expressed as:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

and in Haskell:

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

I would have expected Haskell to evaluate faster or around the same time, but if using a number above say n=40, python code evaluates much (~x3) faster. I'm using GHCi and Ipython but I didn't think that should make a difference.

Comment: You are using a functional technique for your python code? if you really want to compare speed you should play to each languages strength. try something like
...    if n<2: return 1
...    b2,b1 = 1,1
...    for x in xrange(n-2):
...       b2,b1 = b1,b1+b2
...    return b1

Comment: @cmd Using an exponential algorithm in one language and a linear in another is hardly a fair (or sensible) comparison. This is just like Adam's suggestion only in reverse.

Comment: @cmd I'm trying to understand why one language (Python in this case) will execute the same algorithm faster under specific conditions.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that nobody optimizes their language implementations around code that's guaranteed to be unacceptably slow no matter how well you compile/interpret it. Look at it this way: If you submitted a patch that made a non-naive `fib` return in 1.3us instead of 2.6us, but also made this naive `fib` take 112s instead of 38s, there's a good chance it would be accepted; the other way around, I'm absolutely certain it would be rejected.

Comment: @abarnert That depends on why the naive fib would be slower. If the naive fib went from 38s to 112s because your patch made recursion significantly slower, it would most certainly rejected - at least from GHC. It's not like there are certain classes of optimizations or pessimizations that only apply to code with exponential runtime. They apply to all code that uses certain features or patterns and the "recurse twice and then combine the results" is not inherently flawed just because there's a much better alternative for the specific case of `fib`.

Comment: @sepp2k: Actually, there _have_ been changes to GHC that sped up tail recursion at a minor cost to stack recursion. (Admittedly, I can't think of a Python analogue, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.) But the larger point is that nobody's going to put a naive-fib function in a benchmark, no developer is going to find the timing of this function an itch they want to scratch, and nobody's going to get something checked in that improves this unless they can find an actually useful test case with the same problem, which means it's a bad test for a language/implementation shootout.

Comment: @sepp2k you missed the point sepp2k, the point is use the strengths of each language to solve the "problem".  Solving a problem the wrong way and see who detects that you did it wrong and optimizes it to the correct way is really a bad test of language speed.

Comment: @cmd "Solving a problem the wrong way and see who detects that you did it wrong and optimizes it to the correct way is really a bad test of language speed." That would possibly be a valid point if you suggested changing **both** versions to solve the problem the right way, but you only suggested changing the Python version.

Comment: @cmd As I said, my interest was not so much in solving the specific problem. I only wanted to understand the fundamental cause of the difference in evaluation time in running the same algorithm (I now understand that it is related to the way Haskell handles non-strict functions). 
It's not a test for "language speed" either as this can have many different meanings. I think understanding the cause of a syntactically-identical algorithm taking longer to evaluate in one language than another can help me understand some of the concepts of those languages.

Comment: @sepp2k reread my original comment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You said that you ran the Haskell code in GHCI, which means that you ran it without optimizations. That means that no strictness analysis was done, so the whole thing was evaluated lazily, creating a lot of unnecessary thunks. That would explain why it was slower.

Also as delnan pointed out in a comment, ghci is much slower than compiling the code with ghc and then running it - even without optimizations. When I test your code on my PC, running after compiling without optimizations takes twice as long as with optimizations, but still less time than running the Python code. Running in ghci takes a whole lot longer than that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something I don't understand why lazy evaluation should matter here, the Fibonacci sequence has to be evaluated in series, so what is the fundamental reason that lazy evaluation causes it to slow down? Is it something to do with lazy evaluation meaning that memory is not prealocated or am I barking up the wrong tree? This information isn't that easy to find unfortunately.

Comment: Plus, GHCi is probably not optimized for performance, while CPython has numerous optimizations, which make it reasonably fast for an interpreter.

Comment: @MikeVella As I said, it creates a lot of thunks. Basically, in cases where lazy evaluation does not lead to asymptotically better runtime (because of not having to evaluate everything), it will always lead to runtime with worse constant factors if it is not optimized away.

Comment: Thanks @sepp2k. Could you recommend a source where I can read more about this?

Comment: @MikeVella At a glance [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) looks okay, but I haven't actually read it (beyond skimming it just now).

Answer (score 0):

This is the fib implementation that I see the most in haskell examples:

```
fib n = fibs!!n
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Try it vs the python code, it may be much faster.  It is not a direct translation, but perhaps more idiomatic.

This is not a direct answer, but perhaps no one looking to have an optimized fib would use the naive implementation you are using there.  Therefore, this isn't the best way to compare the performance of python and haskell.

More on [Fib in haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence)

Comment: Of course this will perform better than the Python code - it's a whole different algorithm, having linear instead of exponential runtime. That's not a fair comparison.

Comment: As sepp2k points out this one blows the other code out of the water - but it's not an equivalent algorithm. My interest is in understanding the source of the difference in speeds for what appear to be equivalent algorithms.

Comment: @sepp2k Actually, quadratic runtime when you consider the cost of adding numbers that aren't fixed-size. But still way better than exponential.

Comment: Better use a strict version to prevent thunks to overflow the stack when calculating big series. Like `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith' (+) fibs (tail fibs)` where `zipWith' fn (!x:xs) (!y:ys) = fn x y : zipWith' f xs ys` . *Now try to beat this version with Python code ;-)*